# How can I use a Rails engine inside a Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra, rails-engines

I've created a basic Rails engine (I'm using Rails 4), and I've integrated it into my main Rails app via the Gemfile:

```
gem 'app_core', :path => '../app_core'
```

I also added that to my Sinatra app, and bundle install said the gem installed there. I'm testing this in my Sintra app like follows:

```
get '/products.?:format?' do
  AppCore::Product.all.to_json
end
```

When I do this I get:

```
NameError at /products
uninitialized constant AppCore::Product
```

Any ideas how to work around this? Is it possible to integrate an engine into a Sinatra app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working using a gem instead of an Engine. I simply could not make Sinatra use a Rails Engine, but it will use a custom gem just fine. So, I added this to the Rails app and Sinatra app Gemfiles:

```
gem 'app_core', :path => '../app_core'
```

and then in the Sinatra app main file I had to do this:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'app_core'
```

Voila!

Comment: What did you mean by 'I simply could not make Sinatra use a Rails Engine, but it will use a custom gem just fine". Did you modify a Rails Engine to convert it to a 'custom gem'?

Comment: I just created a gem and used that gem in my Sinatra project. Nothing fancy. Do you need me to elaborate more (happy to do so if needed)?

Comment: Cool. So you just created a new gem from scratch that was compatible with Sinatra?

Comment: Well, I didn't have to do anything extra to make it compatible with Sinatra, AFAIK. Have a look at this gem project: https://github.com/chaddjohnson/trading_core. This one is not used in a Sinatra app, but I believe it's exactly the same setup.